# Can't get android service to work

Tags: java, android, service, background

I'm very new to android. I want to create an application that turns off all sounds at the selected time. I created a service with some code and in Eclipse there's no errors, but when I press the button nothing happens. I can see in Application Manager that my program and the service SilentHours are running. Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.silencecontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_NAME = "sending silentHour value to service SilenceHours";

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
   }

    public void setSilenceHours(View view) {
        EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if(editText1.length() > 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SilentHours.class);
            String editText1String = editText1.getText().toString();
            int silentHour = Integer.parseInt(editText1String);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, silentHour);
            this.startService(intent);
        } else {
            textView1.setText("Please enter the silence hour. ");
        }
   }

}
```

SilentHours.java

```
package com.example.silencecontrol;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class SilentHours extends Service {
    public SilentHours() {
    }

    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        int silentHour = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME));
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentTime = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if(currentTime >= silentHour) {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

And by the way I can't @Override the onHandleIntent method. If I put the `@Override` annotation I get error:

> The method onHandleIntent(Intent) of type SilentHours must override or implement a supertype method.

Is that annotation necessary?

Comment: so how will it work just by an intent .. ! I mean onHandleIntent will just run once, for the call, condition fails, service runs without any effect... ! I will advice you to use Android AlarmManager !

Comment: @twntee Why? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: no nothing wrong. You will just learn what `@Override` means. When it is important !

Comment: see going by your code, if i intrepet it right 1)user enters a time 2)you get the time convert it to integer, 3) you start a service and pass the time to it 4)the service on receiving the intent gets the time value, compares it with current time, if it evaluates true->okay all silent, but if it evaluates false->service keeps on running without any result. What you need is an alarm manager which will start the service each day at a specified time, and then you don't need the condition to check if current time is greater than silent hour.

Comment: @twtnee Yes, you're right about my algorythm, but it should work with the condition too but it doesn't...

Comment: Even if I remove the condition in onStartCommand method and leave only the commands to turn off the sounds still nothing happens.

Comment: hmm than you found the error yourself !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are looking for is named [`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29), not `onHandleIntent`.

And no, it's not necessary to add this annotation to an overriden method, it's just a very good practice as you can get sure that you respected the signature of the super class.

Let you IDE help you when you code. Simply type "on" then ask for completion to see which method you can override.

Comment: I just changed the onHandleIntent to onStartCommand(intent) but when I press the button that calls setSilenceHours method nothing happens...

Comment: Log to see if your service gets called.

Comment: I can see in application manager that my service is running but nothing happens. It just runs... Or you mean something else?

Comment: I fixed it! I just used the IntentService subclass instead of Service class, but there was a bug at this line: 

    int silentHour = Integer.parseInt(editText1String);

I shouldn't convert the "EditText" object value to "int" here because I do it in service's method onHandleIntent like this: 

    int silentHour = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NAME));

Now everything wokrs just fine! Thank you guys anyway.

Comment: A good way to thank on stack over flow is to accept the given answer. ;)